# SQL Query to express output from a Pivot Query as a percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following SQL Query running in SQL Server 2014 and it works fine. Now I need to modify the query so that the output is expressed as a percentage (more details on this below).

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT [PropertyCode],
           [MTH],
           [ROOM NIGHTS]
    FROM   HOLDINGS) a
   PIVOT (Sum([ROOM NIGHTS])
         FOR [MTH] IN ([NOVEMBER 2014],
                       [DECEMBER 2014],
                       [JANUARY 2015])) AS PVTTABLE
```

HOLDINGS in the query above is a View Table.

The output from the above query looks like this:

```
PropertyCode   NOVEMBER 2014    DECEMBER 2014  JANUARY 2015
HOTEL A          1,200              560            700
HOTEL B          900                430            500
HOTEL C          800                650            200
```

HOTEL A has 65 rooms, Hotel B 120 rooms and Hotel C has 50 rooms and these info are located in a table called CAPACITY with columns "PropertyCode" and "Rooms" (listing the number of rooms as mentioned above).

I need to modify my pivot query so that the output looks like below:

```
PropertyCode   NOVEMBER 2014    DECEMBER 2014  JANUARY 2015
HOTEL A          61%               28%             35%
HOTEL B          25%               11%             13%
HOTEL C          53%               42%             13%
```

The percentages are calculated like this:
ROOM NIGHTS / (No of Rooms of specific hotel * Days in Month) * 100

I think I need a LEFT JOIN to match the PropertyCode from the HOLDINGS view Table and the CAPACITY table and I will also need to modify the "PIVOT (Sum([ROOM NIGHTS])" part in my original query so that it calculates the output as a % but I'm stuck about how to write the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something on these lines should work:

```
SELECT  [PropertyCode],[MTH], 
[NOVEMBER 2014]/(SELECT rooms FROM capacity c WHERE c.propertycode=pvttable.propertycode)*30*100. as nov2014, 
[DECEMBER 2014]/(SELECT rooms FROM capacity c WHERE c.propertycode=pvttable.propertycode)*31*100. as dec2014, 
[JANUARY 2015]/(SELECT rooms FROM capacity c WHERE c.propertycode=pvttable.propertycode)*31*100.  as jan2015
FROM   (SELECT [PropertyCode],
           [MTH],
           [ROOM NIGHTS]
    FROM   HOLDINGS) a
   PIVOT (Sum([ROOM NIGHTS])
         FOR [MTH] IN ([NOVEMBER 2014],
                       [DECEMBER 2014],
                       [JANUARY 2015])) AS PVTTABLE
```

Or using JOIN instead of correlated queries:

```
SELECT  [PropertyCode],[MTH], 
[NOVEMBER 2014]/rooms * 30 * 100. AS Nov2014, 
[DECEMBER 2014]/rooms * 31 * 100. AS Dec2014, 
[JANUARY 2015]/rooms  * 31 * 100. AS Jan2015
FROM   (SELECT [PropertyCode],
           [MTH],
           [ROOM NIGHTS]
    FROM   HOLDINGS) a
   PIVOT (Sum([ROOM NIGHTS])
         FOR [MTH] IN ([NOVEMBER 2014],
                       [DECEMBER 2014],
                       [JANUARY 2015])) AS PVTTABLE
JOIN capacity c ON c.propertycode=pvttable.propertycode
```

Comment: Thanks. I inserted a couple of brackets along your proposed solution and it worked brilliantly:
[DECEMBER 2014]/(((SELECT rooms FROM HotelInventory c WHERE c.propertycode=pvttable.propertycode)*31)/100) as Dec2014
I now just need the output to be one decimal place or look like "89%" with the % sign added.

Comment: I tried the following regarding the addition of the % sign:
[DECEMBER 2014]/(((SELECT rooms FROM HotelInventory c WHERE c.propertycode=pvttable.propertycode)*31)/100) + '%' as Dec2014
but it gives me an error msg "Error converting data type varchar to float."
I would be glad if you could help here regarding the one decimal place and the % sign.

Comment: There are a few steps you may need to do; sql server is not very good at formatting.

Comment: you can make the result yield a float if you add a dot in the constants like 31. * 100. in this way it will implicitly cast rooms to float and then the division as float too. Then the format bit you can do through explicit casts: cast(cast([DECEMBER 2014]/(((SELECT rooms FROM HotelInventory c WHERE c.propertycode=pvttable.propertycode)*31.)/100.) as decimal (9,1)) as varchar) + '%'

Comment: Fabulous! Works a treat!